# How to find nested html elements using lxml in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am trying to scrape the following html.

There are multiple divs where class="review-card".

Each of these divs always contain a script element where data-initial-state="data-always-exist" and sometimes contain a script element where data-initial-state="data-may-not-exist".

I would like to retrieve the data from both of these script elements. When the second one does not exist I want to return a specific value e.g. 0.

As you can see on my code below, I have managed to find the "retrieve-card" div elements. However, I fail to retrieve the script element that live inside each div element. My code always returns a list vs a single element. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="review-list">
                <div class="review-card">
                    <article class="review">
                        <script type="application.json" data-initial-state="data-always-exist">
                        {"reviewBody":"Brilliant value","stars":5}
                        </script>
                        <section class="review__content">
                            <div class="content">
                                <script type="application.json" data-initial-state="data-may-not-exist">
                                    {"isVerified":true,"verificationSource":"invitation"}
                                </script>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div class="review-card">
                    <article class="review">
                            <script type="application.json data-initial-state="data-always-exist">
                                {"reviewBody":"Brilliant value","stars":5}
                            </script>
                    </article>
                </div>
                <div class="review-card">
                    <article class="review">
                        <script type="application.json" data-initial-state="data-always-exist">
                        {"reviewBody":"Great","stars":4}
                        </script>
                        <section class="review__content">
                            <div class="content">
                                <script type="application.json" data-initial-state="data-may-not-exist">
                                    {"isVerified":false,"verificationSource":"invitation"}
                                </script>
                            </div>
                        </section>
                    </article>
                </div>

            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried the following:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://somewebsite.com')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#finds the review list
review_list = tree.xpath('//div[@class="review-list"]')

#finds all the review cards
review_cards = review_list[0].xpath('//div[contains(@class,"review-card")]')

for card in review_cards:
   
   #this part of the code does not work as intended -returns a list vs a single items.
   data_always_exist = card.xpath("//script[starts-with(@data-initial-state, 'data-always-exist')]")
   data_not_always_exist = card.xpath("//script[starts-with(@data-initial-state, 'data-may-not-exist')]")
```

Comment: Is it ok to use `beautifulsoup`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely as a last option yes, but I would prefer a lxml solution.

Comment: I've added BeautifulSoup and lxml version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `beautifulsoup`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://somewebsite.com").content, "lxml")

for card in soup.select(".review-card"):
    print("data-always-exist:")
    d = card.select_one('[data-initial-state="data-always-exist"]')
    if d:
        print(d.contents[0].strip())
    print("data-may-not-exist:")
    d = card.select_one('[data-initial-state="data-may-not-exist"]')
    if d:
        print(d.contents[0].strip())

    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
data-always-exist:
{"reviewBody":"Brilliant value","stars":5}
data-may-not-exist:
{"isVerified":true,"verificationSource":"invitation"}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data-always-exist:
{"reviewBody":"Brilliant value","stars":5}
data-may-not-exist:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
data-always-exist:
{"reviewBody":"Great","stars":4}
data-may-not-exist:
{"isVerified":false,"verificationSource":"invitation"}
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Version with `lxml` (Use dot (`.`) in your XPath):

```
# ...
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
cards = tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"review-card")]')


for card in cards:

    # this part of the code does not work as intended -returns a list vs a single items.
    data_always_exist = card.xpath(
        ".//script[starts-with(@data-initial-state, 'data-always-exist')]"
    )
    data_not_always_exist = card.xpath(
        ".//script[starts-with(@data-initial-state, 'data-may-not-exist')]"
    )

    print(data_always_exist)
    print(data_not_always_exist)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
[<Element script at 0x7fc202aadd10>]
[<Element script at 0x7fc202aade50>]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[<Element script at 0x7fc202aadea0>]
[]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[<Element script at 0x7fc202aade50>]
[<Element script at 0x7fc202aadea0>]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```